# Write an application that calls PowerShell and leaves the console up

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, console-application

I am trying to distribute an application foo.exe on Windows. The application foo is a console app that reads and writes to stdout and has no GUI. It is usually called many times by the user. (It is a port of a Unix app).

I have no experience in writing Windows apps though and no Windows experience. So not sure the best way, but I was thinking as a start: if I could just get an app that invoked PowerShell in a particular directory, then the user could click on that app and get PowerShell started in the right directory. That's all I need.

So how can I package up a .bat file that just invokes Powershell with cd a particular directory, say C:/foo and lets the user type in to that shell. Even if I make a .bat file, if the user just clicks on it will that work?

Comment: Create shortcut to `powershell.exe` and set `C:\foo` as working directory in that shortcut.

Comment: I don't know how to do any of this on my own machine, much less a user's machine. As I said I don't know Windows. I just compiled my existing Unix C++ code with Visual Studio to generate the Windows .exe file.